# Populando GridView sem nenhum registro selecionado

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou populando um GridView e ele está populando com o primeiro registro sempre selecionado.

```
var lstUsurios = new V_ENTIDADE_X_PWDNegocio().Listar();

gdvAcesso.DataSource = lstUsurios; 

gdvAcesso.DataBind();
```

Já tentei alterar algumas propriedades dele e nada...

Como poderia contornar essa situação?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se dá pra **impedir** o Grid de fazer a seleção, mas pra limpar é bem fácil:

```
gdvAcesso.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: no Web Form tambem ?

Comment: Opa, confundi com WinForms. Olha minha resposta editada